# Как создать объект с FileUploader через консоль RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеем модель `Video`

```
# video.rb
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

Как через рельсовую консоль создать объект `Video` с файлом?

Comment: А для uploading'а используется какой-нибудь гем?

Comment: да, carrierwave

Comment: попробуй вариант, который я написал ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из консоли попробуй так:

```
Video.new(:file => File.new(path_to_video_file, "r"))
```

`path_to_video_file` - путь к файлу с видео

Comment: почти сработало. flv файл скачивает в папку uploads все как надо, но поле файл в модели Video почему то просто file: ".flv"